# Remove default output | sns barplot | python

Tags: python, seaborn, jupyter

I'm looking forward to know how to remove the default output of the **library seaborn**. I add the information for the plot with **ax.set**, it implicates a **text output that i don't want to have**, how can I do it keeping the labels and without matplotlib?

[image: visual description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to jupyter

Add a semicolon at the end of the last command, this removes the output:

```
ax.set(...);
```